# How to post on facebook page using php?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I developed a custom CMS to manage news on website and I want to publish these news directly on facebook and website together. I have created an app on Facebook and it works fine as development, but if I want to publish it I have to request a review to use manage_pages and publish_pages permissions, so I have to do a screencast to send to Facebook development team.

Is it right or there is a different solution to make a post on a Facebook page directly with PHP?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: they have to approve it so yeah you need to capture what's going on so they can review it

Comment: definitely not a duplicate, as this is about the new process/review that is needed now.

Answer (score 1):

It is the correct way. In developer mode, only users with a role in the App would see a post made with the API. In order to put the App (and the posts) live, you have to go through the review process.